# Change cursor color when changing input language with Vim

Tags: vim

Today I found the way to change input language in vim by setting in .vimrc `set keymap=_mykeymap_` and using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>^</kbd>.

Is it possible to change cursor color in `insert mode` when changing input language with Vim?

Answer (score 2):

For gvim see `:help lCursor`.

For vim I have no answer, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

In the [vim wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Vim_Tips_Wiki) I found [this](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Configuring_the_cursor):

> It is possible to change the cursor color and style in the terminal if it understands the following escape sequences. Not all terminals support this, but xterm, rxvt and Terminator do. Recent versions of gnome-terminal support the sequence to change color, but not the one to restore the color to the default.

With following in the `.vimrc` you can change the curser color for the different modes:

```
if &term =~ "xterm\\|rxvt"
    " use an orange cursor in insert mode
    let &t_SI = "\<Esc>]12;orange\x7"
    " use a red cursor otherwise
    let &t_EI = "\<Esc>]12;red\x7"
    silent !echo -ne "\033]12;red\007"
    " reset cursor when vim exits
    autocmd VimLeave * silent !echo -ne "\033]112\007"
    " use \003]12;gray\007 for gnome-terminal
endif
```

So you can write a function in which you check the current `keymap` and switch between the "keymap-cursor-colors".

Answer (score 0):

I know how to change the sharp of cursor in `insert mode`, for example, [my setting](https://github.com/Marslo/VimConfig/blob/master/Configurations/vimrc#L291) is:

```
set guicursor=a:hor1
set guicursor+=i-r-ci-cr-o:hor2-blinkon0
```

[Help file](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'guicursor') shows:

```
    n   Normal mode
    v   Visual mode
    ve  Visual mode with 'selection' "exclusive" (same as 'v',
        if not specified)
    o   Operator-pending mode
    i   Insert mode
    r   Replace mode
    c   Command-line Normal (append) mode
    ci  Command-line Insert mode
    cr  Command-line Replace mode
    sm  showmatch in Insert mode
    a   all modes
```

I don't think the color can be changed in a specified mode ([highlight-groups](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/syntax.html#:highlight)). But you can change the color by using(in all mode):

```
hi Cursor               guibg=#A6E22E       guifg=#A6E22E     gui=underline
```

Details can be found from [my color configuration](https://github.com/Marslo/marslo.vim/blob/master/colors/marslo256.vim#L36)